# Cannot set property 'componentInstance' of undefined in unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular15

I have tried different approaches (inject the component by constructor, create the mocks and spies in different ways, inject this spies to the element,...), but in the end I always end up receiving the same error: **Cannot set property 'componentInstance' of undefined**. Can you give me any idea please?

**COMPONENT**

```
openUpdate(rowSelected: iData) {
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogEditComponent, {});
        dialogRef.componentInstance.dialogRef = dialogRef;
        dialogRef.componentInstance.selectedData = rowSelected;
        const sub = dialogRef.componentInstance.onAdd.subscribe((data: iData) => {
            if (data) {
                this.update(data);
            }
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
            sub.unsubscribe();
        });
    }
```

**SPEC.TS**

```
describe('Component1Component', () => {
  let component: Componenet1Component;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Componenet1Component>;
  let dataServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<DataService>;
  let toastrServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ToastrService>;
  let dialogSpy: any;
  let dialogRefSpy: any;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    dialogSpy = {
      open: jasmine.createSpy('open').and.returnValue({
        componentInstance: {
          onAdd: jasmine.createSpyObj('onAdd', ['subscribe'])
        },
        afterClosed: () => {
          return jasmine.createSpyObj('afterClosed', ['subscribe']);
        },
      })
    };
    toastrServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ToastrService', ['success', 'error']);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Component1Component, DialogEditComponent],
      imports: [MatDialogModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatDialog, useValue: dialogSpy },
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: dialogRefSpy },
        { provide: FinalistService, useValue: dataServiceSpy },
        { provide: ToastrService, useValue: toastrServiceSpy },
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CampaignFinalistsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('should open the edit dialog with the selected data', async () => {
    component = new Component1Component(dialogSpy, dataServiceSpy, toastrServiceSpy);

    dialogRefSpy.componentInstance = {
      dialogRef: dialogRefSpy,
      selectedFinalist: mockData[0],
      onAdd: of(mockData[0])
    };

    dialogSpy.open.and.returnValue(dialogRefSpy);

    spyOn(component, 'update');

    component.openUpdate(mockData[0]);

    expect(dialogSpy.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(DialogEditComponent, {});
    expect(dialogRefSpy.componentInstance.selectedData).toEqual(mockData[0]);

    expect(component.update).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockData[0]);
    expect(dialogRefSpy.afterClosed).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

But I receive, as I said, this error continually:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'componentInstance' of undefined
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/app/features/Component1.component.spec.ts:108:35)
            at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
            at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
            at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
            at executor (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:27:1)
            at new ZoneAwarePromise (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1351:25)
            at UserContext.apply (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:19:1)
            at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:409:30)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:303:43)
            at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:408:56)
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a dialogRefSpy object, but you are not initializing it with any value. So, when you try to set the componentInstance property on it, it is still undefined.

you need to initialize the dialogRefSpy object before setting the componentInstance property on it. You can create a new object with the jasmine.createSpyObj function and assign it to dialogRefSpy.componentInstance before calling open.

**SPEC.TS**

```
it('should open the edit dialog with the selected data', async () => {
  component = new Component1Component(dialogSpy, dataServiceSpy, toastrServiceSpy);

  const dialogRefInstanceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('dialogRefInstanceSpy', ['afterClosed', 'close']);
  dialogRefInstanceSpy.selectedData = mockData[0];
  dialogRefInstanceSpy.onAdd = of(mockData[0]);

  dialogRefSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('dialogRefSpy', ['afterClosed']);
  dialogRefSpy.componentInstance = dialogRefInstanceSpy;

  dialogSpy.open.and.returnValue(dialogRefSpy);

  spyOn(component, 'update');

  component.openUpdate(mockData[0]);

  expect(dialogSpy.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(DialogEditComponent, {});
  expect(dialogRefInstanceSpy.selectedData).toEqual(mockData[0]);

  expect(component.update).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockData[0]);
  expect(dialogRefInstanceSpy.afterClosed).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I create a new object dialogRefInstanceSpy with jasmine.createSpyObj and assign it to dialogRefSpy.componentInstance. Then we set the selectedData and onAdd properties on dialogRefInstanceSpy before calling open.

Hope it's helps...

Updated **SPEC.TS**

```
describe('Component1Component', () => {
  let component: Componenet1Component;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Componenet1Component>;
  let dataServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<DataService>;
  let toastrServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ToastrService>;
  let dialogSpy: any;
  let dialogRefSpy: any;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    dialogSpy = {
      open: jasmine.createSpy('open').and.returnValue({
        componentInstance: {
          onAdd: jasmine.createSpyObj('onAdd', ['subscribe'])
        },
        afterClosed: () => {
          return jasmine.createSpyObj('afterClosed', ['subscribe']);
        },
      })
    };
    toastrServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ToastrService', ['success', 'error']);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Component1Component, DialogEditComponent],
      imports: [MatDialogModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatDialog, useValue: dialogSpy },
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: dialogRefSpy },
        { provide: FinalistService, useValue: dataServiceSpy },
        { provide: ToastrService, useValue: toastrServiceSpy },
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CampaignFinalistsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('should open the edit dialog with the selected data', async () => {
  component = new Component1Component(dialogSpy, dataServiceSpy, toastrServiceSpy);

  const dialogRefInstanceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('dialogRefInstanceSpy', ['afterClosed', 'close']);
  dialogRefInstanceSpy.componentInstance = jasmine.createSpyObj('componentInstance', ['onAdd']);
  dialogRefInstanceSpy.componentInstance.onAdd.and.returnValue(of(mockData[0]));
  dialogRefInstanceSpy.selectedData = mockData[0];

  dialogRefSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('dialogRefSpy', ['afterClosed']);
  dialogRefSpy.componentInstance = dialogRefInstanceSpy;

  dialogSpy.open.and.returnValue(dialogRefSpy);

  spyOn(component, 'update');

  component.openUpdate(mockData[0]);

  expect(dialogSpy.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(DialogEditComponent, {});
  expect(dialogRefInstanceSpy.selectedData).toEqual(mockData[0]);

  expect(component.update).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockData[0]);
  expect(dialogRefInstanceSpy.componentInstance.onAdd).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(dialogRefInstanceSpy.afterClosed).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think it worked, now I am receiving the next error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined.

Comment: @Kenzo_Gilead I have updated my answer and in the last of the answer I have added the code of the spec file please try it i think solved your subscribe error

Comment: Now, I receive: TypeError: Cannot read property 'onAdd' of undefined

Comment: @Kenzo_Gilead again i update please check

Comment: Thanks again. Now I receive this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
        at Component1Component.openUpdate (src/app/features/Component1.component.ts:57:49)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/app/features/Component.component.spec.ts:122:15). Being 57 -> const sub = dialogRef.componentInstance.onAdd.subscribe((data: iData) => {. And 122 -> component.openUpdate(mockData[0]);. Thanks so much again for your help.

Comment: it is being called on dialogRef.componentInstance.onAdd, which appears to have been created using a spy object in the beforeEach block.

Comment: it seems that dialogRef is not being defined or initialized properly, and this is causing the error when trying to access its componentInstance.

To resolve this issue, you may want to double-check that the dialogRef object is properly initialized in the beforeEach block, and that it is being passed correctly to the Component1Component constructor when it is instantiated. You could also try adding some console.log statements to help debug the issue and see what values are being passed around.